# Vue 3 - Watching prop stops working after emitting to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch, prop

I have an issue trying to watch a prop in a child component. Here's a playground link with a a little code to reproduce the issue:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

The child component (in orange) inherits the data from the parent (just an array). The child component copies the data from the parent whenever it changes, and you can then modify (append) to the child data, and when you click <kbd>save</kbd>, the data should be emitted into the parent (and is then subsequently passed into the child as a prop).

The problem is, as soon as you click <kbd>save</kbd> in the child component, the child is no longer able to watch for changes to the prop. It never sees the future changes from the parent. Vue devtools correctly sees the data though. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) composable accepts either a 'ref', 'reactive' object, or a getter function.

But as stated in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example), it doesn't accept inner property of a reactive object:

> Do note that you can't watch a property of a reactive object like this:
>
> ```
> const obj = reactive({ count: 0 })
> // this won't work because we are passing a number to watch()
> watch(obj.count, (count) => {
>  console.log(`count is: ${count}`)
> })
> ```

So to listen to `props.list` changes, you need to use a getter function:

```js
watch(() => props.list, () => {
  // ...
})
```

See this [working playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: I guess, the props.list is yet reactive. It's just get replaced by the `add` event. Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75083686/2487565

Comment: I updated my answer to bring more details on why it didn't work. `props` is reactive, but `props.list` doesn't trigger the watcher without using a getter function.

Comment: Yes, but it still does work for `props.list` in the original playground until the `list` array gets replaced. Anyway, you answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your watcher like:

```
  watch(
    () => props.list,
      (newValue, oldValue) => {
        console.log('updated!');
        internalCopy.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.list));
     }, {
    immediate: true,
   deep: true,
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not in a computed property, Issue is in your `onAdd` method. As this is an array, It should be update by `reference` not a `value`.

```
  const onAdd = (val) => {
    // data.value.list = val; ❌ 
    val.forEach((d, index) => {
      data.value.list[index] = d ✅
    })
  }
```

Working [`Vue SFC Playground`](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: If in new val theres removed 1 item he will still be in data.value.list

Answer (score 0):

It is also working well with deep watch on `props` object, like so:

```
watch(props, () => {
  console.log('updated!');
  internalCopy.value = props.list;
}, {
  immediate: true,
  deep: true,
})
```

Since the `ref` (reference) to the `props` object keeps unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question to deeply understand the Vue reactivity. That's why I wanted to clarify it completely .

The previous answers are correct, but they don't explain the problem fully enough for me.

Since the `props.list` is a `ref` (reference) to the the array, when you define your `watcher` with it, then the watcher is bound to this `ref` (a `Proxy` object) and it will stay bounded to this `ref` even if you replace the `props.list` with a new `ref` to an new array. This is what you do with your `add` event.

To check it I have added the `refBackup` with the original `ref` to see it the watcher still updates, it we update the original `list` array through `refBackup`. Like this:

```
const refBackup = ref(props.list);

const addToBack = () => {
  refBackup.value.push('addToBack');
}
```

Notice that updating the `refBackup` triggers the `watcher()`, even after the <kbd>save</kbd> was clicked and the `props.list` points now to another `ref` with a new Array.

Here is the link to my [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

In case when you define your `watcher()` with the function `() => props.list`,
this function always returns the actual `ref` to the last updated array. The watcher is bound to the function and not to the `ref` of `props.list` array.